# How to tackle browser's back and forward buttons/arrows?

Tags: gui-design, navigation, browser, back-button, ease-of-use

What is the general UX rule followed wrt to navigation that a browser provides.
I am developing a web based tool.I would be definately be enabling navigation to different screens within the tool, I want to understand should the same be allowed through the browser or not?

Comment: Leave them alone. Trying to switch them off or mess with their behaviour just annoys people who have come to rely on them working in a specific way.

Answer (score 3):

The browser has back and forward buttons whether we like it or not. I would work with that.

If the buttons are present but made non-functional by the developer, the end-user is likely to find the experience frustrating.

Comment: The application should also ideally *accept* that the buttons exist and that pressing them should behave in the normal manner. For example, SPA (single page applications) use hash-tag navigation to produce browser history entries that can then move forward and backwards between application state.